# Debugging an App that does not have a launcher Activity

Tags: android, adb, android-debug

My current application does not have any activities. It is basically a bunch of services android components without an activity launcher (*just like the title says*). Basically it gets self triggered with broadcast receivers from the Android OS.

I'm having a hard time attaching my debugger to my android process to debug the App.

Any idea how to force the debugger to attach to the app?

Comment: *My current application does not have any activities.* then obviously will not works ... (on API 13+)

Comment: @Selvin No, it does work. Not because you do not have activities that your application is not going to work. You can totally have an application with only Services, Content providers, and Broadcast receivers. Also, I can see my logs functioning and my app running, the only part that is tricky right now is attaching Debugger to the Android Process. (my android:minSdkVersion = 15)

Comment: no, it will not *[Applications are in a stopped state when they are first installed but are not yet launched](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols)* such application will not getting any broadcasts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Debug.waitingForDebugger()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#waitForDebugger()) utility method for that.

From the documentation:

> Wait until a debugger attaches. As soon as the debugger attaches, this returns, so you will **need to place a breakpoint after the waitForDebugger()** call if you want to start tracing immediately.

Comment: I did add Debug.waitingForDebugger() and I think it's a clever idea, however I'm not able to attach the debugger to the Android app from the Android Studio "Attach Debugger to Android Process".

Comment: How would you use this? Can I just add it to my application class and leave it there or will it wait for a debugger even when the debugger isn't being used?

Comment: That's correct. The application will hang until you attach the debugger, which means you should never add this to production code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit. Adding to what @Edson suggested, I forgot to set the `debuggable true` on my build types, because it is set to `false` by default. Now it's working !